# How to stop the Maven assembly plugin from deploying the artifact it creates

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am using the maven assembly plugin to combine two jars together using the following configuration:

```
<execution>
    <id>Package jar with dependencies</id>
    <phase>compile</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

I DO NOT want the JAR that I create with the assembly plugin to be deployed, how can I stop it from being deployed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should specify the following configuration option for assembly plugin:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <attach>false</attach>
  ...
</configuration>
```