# Stop specific maven-jar-plugin executions from being installed/deployed

Tags: java, maven, maven-jar-plugin

I have a Maven project that generates additional JARs via `maven-jar-plugin` that are used for test purposes:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>some-other-sources</id>
                        <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/some-other-sources</testClassesDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/some-other-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <classifier>some-other-sources</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The additional `some-other-sources` should not be `instal`led to the local repository (or `deploy`ed to the remote).

Is there a way to specify that these `maven-jar-plugin` outputs should be generated and put in the `target` folder **only**?

Comment: currently, you can't force `maven-jar-plugin` to not attach supplemental artifacts, however you may take advantage of `maven-assembly-plugin` [features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530453/how-to-stop-the-maven-assembly-plugin-from-deploying-the-artifact-it-creates)